# Fact and Dimension Data-warehouse Datamart

Tags: data-warehouse, datamart

I have two fact tables (purchase and defect )
and both of them  are linked to the same dimension.
So my question can i combine the two fact to a single fact table (put all the KPI in a single Fact table ).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A fact table must have a grain defined for it and all measures must adhere to that grain. So if you have two fact tables with the same grain then, technically, you could combine them into a single fact table. Whether that make sense from a usage perspective is a different question.

I assume that your fact tables are linked to more than one dimension each? The fact that they have a dimension in common doesn't mean you can combine them.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,yes both of table are linked to the same dimension that's why i thought i should combine them